# Сделать dump базы используя только SQL

Tags: postgresql

Соединение через ssh невозможно от слово совсем. Есть только коннект через библиотеку Psycopg2 на python. Необходимо сделать (или спровоцировать сделать дб) дамп базы данных, как будто я использовал утилиту "pg_dump". Формат сохраненного файла не важен. Сам дамп пусть лежит на сервере где установлен postgresql.Версия базы 10. Повторюсь могу делать только execute через соединение. Заранее благодарен за потраченное время.

Comment: Если вы можете подключиться к базе через python, значит точно так же вы можете подключиться к базе через pg_dump с опцией `--host`, предварительно установив этот самый pg_dump на свой компьютер, никакой ssh для этого не нужен

Comment: Правда, условие «дамп пусть лежит на сервере» всё усложняет